# Data validation for a date within 2 calendar years

Tags: validation, date, ms-access

How would you do Data Validation to check a date within 2 calendar years? For example, if the date entered is 4/1/2015, that year and the following year both validate. 1/1/2017 would be the first year to not validate.

I assumed it would be

```
>Year(Date())-1
```

but this is not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It would be:

```
Year([DateEntered]) >= Year(Date()) And Year([DateEntered]) <= Year(Date()) + 1
```

or:

```
[DateEntered] >= DateSerial(Year(Date()), 1, 1) And [DateEntered] <= DateSerial(Year(Date()) + 1, 12, 31)
```